# Adding table header vertically in Cakephp

Tags: cakephp, tableheader

This is my code for adding table header

```
 echo $this->Html->tableHeaders(
    array(
        'Vacancycard id',
      'Date',
      'Starting time',
      'Starting point',
          'Destination point',
        'Status',
          'Action'
              )
            );
```

this is works fine.but i want to add table header vertically..
is there any possible way?

for example this outputs

**heading1*heading2**heading3**heading4**heading5**

i want this heading horizontally

ie;

**heading1**

**heading2**

**heading3**

**heading4**

also corresponding table iinformation too.ie, table cells

```
  echo $this->Html->tableCells
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you want the text to display vertically, rather than horizontally, the CSS transform property is what you want:

```
th {
    transform: rotate(270deg);
}
```

It's not supported in older versions of IE though - http://caniuse.com/transforms2d

Comment: Ah yes, I understand - I'm afraid I don't know the answer